# axios response.data != JSON.parse(response.request.response)

Tags: javascript, json, axios

I do following axios request:

```
const response = await axios({
  url,
  method,
  headers: headersObject,
  data,
  params: params || {},
});
```

And then i check the `response`:

```
console.log('response.request.response')
console.log(JSON.parse(response.request.response))
console.log('data')
console.log(response.data)
```

Surprising, the `response.data` is different then `JSON.parse(response.request.response)`. I have an array - property `labels` at `response.data` object that is `undefined`, and an array `labels` in `JSON.parse(response.request.response)` that contains exact labels that i am expecting. There is some issue with converting axios data to object when the value of some json key is an array?

Comment: I would suggest you make sure the server is providing a response with the `Content-Type: application/json` header, then use directly the response.data object.

Comment: @Francesco Server is providing response with the `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so magic asynchronous thing going there with console.log(). response.data finally is the same as JSON.parse(response.request.response), but not in this particular moment when i am printing this on the console.